Spring stream kafka events with multiple output topics
I have a springboot app that sends kafka events to a topic with a specific avro schema. The demo code is as so:
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class KafkaListener {

  @Bean
  public Function<List<DummyClass>, List<DummyClass>> acceptEvent() {
     return messages -> {
        List<DummyClass> output = new ArrayList<>();
        messages.forEach(msg -> {
          // do work and add items to the output field
        });
        // some more work
        return output;
     };
  }
}

And DummyClass class is a class generated by avro schema (.avsc file being defined in the resources folder and generated by the avro plugin).
So a fairly standard set up. Now, instead of sending events to a single topic like I do now with the code above, I want to be able to send events to 2 topics.
After searching online, I found a spring documentation illustrating an example using tuples. So I gave it a go and implemented it all but the flux part (as I don't want it). The new code end up being as so:
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class KafkaListener {

  @Bean
  public Function<List<DummyClass>, Tuple2<List<DummyClass>,List<DummyClass>>> acceptEvent() {
     return messages -> {
        List<DummyClass> output1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<DummyClass> output2 = new ArrayList<>();
        messages.forEach(msg -> {
          // do work and add items to the output1 and output2 fields
        });
        // some more work
        return Tuples.of(output1,output2);
     };
  }
}

However, that does not seem to work as I am getting the following exception:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: At the moment only Tuple-based function are supporting multiple arguments

I suspect that this is due to me not using flux. This answer suggested that wrong imports might be in use but I verified that everything that I use is from correct imports.
A slightly different implementation has encountered a similar problem as specified in this article. However, this person managed to resolve the issue by passing a custom object containing output arguments as fields. I have attempted to do the same but running the app results in the following exception:
Unsupported Avro type. Supported types are null, Boolean, Integer, Long, Float, Double, String, byte[] and IndexedRecord

And with that, I have exhausted my options for now. My question is then as follows:
How can I achieve writing events to multiple topics? And if one of my implementations is the way, what did I do wrong? Is there other things to try? - I have seen KStream which said to be able to do what I want but I cannot seem to find a good code example.

The below answer in almost certain one of many possible solutions but it end being good enough for me, so closing this ticket.

After some back and forth, I found the streamBridge being the best option to achieve that.
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@AllArgsContstractor
public class KafkaListener {

  private final StreamBridge streamBridge;

  @Bean
  public Function<List<DummyClass>, List<DummyClass>> acceptEvent() {
     return messages -> {
        List<DummyClass> output = new ArrayList<>();
        messages.forEach(msg -> {
          // do work and add items to the output field you want to be sent to topic 1
          if(condition) {
            Message<DummyClass> msgToSendViaStreamBridge = createMsg(); // method to create an event for streamBridge to send to the topic 2
            streamBridge.send("acceptEvnet-out-1", msgToSendViaStreamBridge);
          }
        });
        // some more work
        return output;
     };
  }
}

So now my Function will send events to existing topic (defined by acceptEvnet-out-0 binding in application.yml file) that would be put into the output list. And we send events to a different topic defined in acceptEvnet-out-1 binding. This can be used to send events to as many topics as you want.
